# iOS code sign error

Tags: ios, xcode9, p12

Apologies if this has been asked before. I am new to iOS mobile app development. I am further developing an iOS app that has been developed by another person. They sent me the source code and told me that all the signing keys/certificates/provisioning profiles are stored against the Apple Developer's Account (which I have access to). When I try to build/run the app through XCode it complains about Code Sign error (not having a matching certificate in my keychain) [image: screenshot attached]. How can I fix this error please? is the a way to download the.p12 file from the app's Apple Developer Account? Since the app provisioning profile and signing identity is only needed for running the app on actual devices (at least in my understanding), is there away of getting xcode to ignore about it just for the purpose of running the app on the simulator?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a developer account add it to Xcode Preferences -> Accounts , then click **Automatically manage signing**

Comment: Thank you. Will that still work if I want to deploy and distribute the app to the app store?

Comment: if you are the owner of the account , or have an admin role then yes it'll work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to distribute the app, make sure you have a distribution private key in your keychain, from the old mac or create the new one

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Just export the private cer from your mac who have acces distribution, or register a new one on apple developer console 